# c++ Convert string to bytes to send over tcp

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, c++-cli, tcp, bitconverter

I'm trying to send a 28 character string to a remote ip address and port. I've done this successfully in vb.net using the following code snippets:

```
Dim swon As String = "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8"
Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(swon)
netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
```

I now have to convert this across to c++ and have the following so far:

```
char *swon = "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8";
array<Byte>^ sendBuffer = gcnew array<Byte>(bufferSize);
sendBuffer = BitConverter::GetBytes( swon );
tcpStream->Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer->Length);
```

but am getting stuck at this point. I'm sure I'm missing a simple syntax error but I can't figure it out!

To clarify, I'm not getting an error, but I don't think the string is being converted to bytes correctly as when I convert back, I just get a '01'

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are not just using the exact same .Net framework classes in your ++/CLI code.  eg. `System::String` for `swon`, `Encoding::ASCII` to produce the array of bytes.

Anything you did in VB you can map **directly** over to C++/CLI without using different classes - that's the easest port for you.  When you are in MSDN online, just select the `C++` view to get examples of stuff you want to do.  Try that on this page, for example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx

Comment: Many thanks, that's the answer I was looking for! Its just a syntax question, sendBuffer = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(swoff); works with strings rather than char

Comment: It should not be very hard, since your VB.Net code is already working. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Steve is correct that the same logic can be duplicated in C++.  But the C++ `char*` already is ASCII, no conversion is necessary.  Just a copy is all that's needed.

```
const char swon[] = { "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8" };
array<Byte>^ sendBuffer = gcnew array<Byte>((sizeof swon) - 1);
pin_ptr<Byte> startBuffer = &sendBuffer[0];
memcpy(startBuffer, swon, sendBuffer->Length);
tcpStream->Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer->Length);
```